# How to Create a Data Table Visualization in Kibana with Nested Aggregation Fields?

Tags: kibana, virtualization

I'm trying to create a visualization in Kibana where I display the data from my Elasticsearch index in a data table format. However, when I select the "Terms" aggregation, the "violation_list" field does not appear. My goal is to display the "key" field under a column labeled "Value" and the "doc_count" field under a column labeled "Count". How can I achieve this?

Index Mapping;

```
{
  "properties": {
    "@timestamp": {
      "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis||yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm:ssz",
      "index": true,
      "ignore_malformed": false,
      "store": false,
      "type": "date",
      "doc_values": true
    },
    "app_log_id": {
      "type": "keyword"
    },
    "app_name": {
      "type": "keyword"
    },
    "violation_list": {
      "type": "nested",
      "properties": {
        "type": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "value": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Query;

```
POST /xxx/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "violation_counts": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "violation_list"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "violation_values": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "violation_list.value",
            "size": 100
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Response;

```
{
  "took": 550,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 9539,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "violation_counts": {
      "doc_count": 9751,
      "violation_values": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 13,
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key": "Bertug",
            "doc_count": 2610
          },
          {
            "key": "Mete",
            "doc_count": 1510
          }
          // Other buckets...
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```